# Как добавить несколько background?

Tags: css

свойство background-image позволяет перезаписать несколько картинок, через запятую

```
.first.second.third.fourth {
    background-image: url(first.png), url(second.png), url(third.png), url(fourth.png);
}
```

есть ли возможность не перезаписывать, а добавить картинку к уже имеющемуся фону?

```
.first {
    background-image: url(first.png);
}
.second {
    background-image: url(second.png);
}
.third {
    background-image: url(third.png);
}
.fourth {
    background-image: url(fourth.png);
}
```

**КОЛЛЕГИ**, Вы вопрос не дочитали, уточню:

как Multiple Backgrounds разбить на несколько CSS-классов?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121341/discussion-on-question-by-ravend----background).

Answer (score 1):

попробуй сокращённой записью, должно работать, но для изображения кооторое сверху фона задай позиционирование и размеры как тебе нравиться

```
background: url(first.png) center center / 50% no-repeat fixed,url(second.png);
```